# Balanced tree recursion: Why is my solution unbearably slow?

Tags: c, recursion, tree

**The origin problem is:**

Define the height of a binary tree to be the number of nodes in the longest path from the root to a leaf. The empty tree is considered to have height 0. A node is k-balanced if its left and right subtrees differ in height by at most k. A tree is k-balanced if all of its nodes are k-balanced. The empty tree is considered to be k-balanced.

For example, the tree below has height 4.

```
       o
      / \
     o   o
    / \
   o   o
      /
     o
```

This tree is 2-balanced but not 1-balanced, because the left subtree of the root has height 3 and the right subtree of the root has height 1. 
Your task is to write a method that takes a balance factor k and a number of nodes n and returns the maximum height of a k-balanced tree with n nodes.

**One of the answer(right and fast) is:**

```
int fewest_node(int k,int h)
{
    if(h <= 0)
        return 0;
    return 1+fewest_node(k,h-1)+fewest_node(k,h-1-k);
}

int maxHeight2(int k, int n)
{
    for(int h = 1;;h++)
        if(fewest_node(k,h) > n)
            return h - 1;
}
```

**and my solution(terribly slow) is:**

```
int maxHeight(int k, int n)
{
    int i,left,right;
    if(k >= n)
        return n;
    if(n > 2)
    {
        left = maxHeight(k,n-1);
        if(left <= k)
            return left+1;
        else
        {
            i = n - 2;
            left = maxHeight(k,i);
            right = maxHeight(k,n-1-i);
            while((left - right) > k)
            {
                i--;
                left = maxHeight(k,i);
                right = maxHeight(k,n-1-i);
            }
            return left+1;
        }
    }
    else 
        return n;
}
```

**My question:**

1.Is my solution right?I mean it does work regardlessly of its efficiency? Or in other words,is it right logically?(BTW,I think it's right,and I have tested the output when n is less than 30)

2.Why is my solution sooooo slow?
As you can see, I'm a newbie on DSA, and it's my first question here.So any tips or explanations are appreciated.

Comment: I think this question would be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I dunno, but recurrence in a while loop would be my 1st bet why it's slow. Also you are double checking things http://ideone.com/J6IRBu.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry,I am a newcomer,I just want to learn something about recursion(such as time complexcity),not just the question itself.

Comment: @luk32,anyway,thanks for your code.It helps me to some degree.

Comment: Well then I suggest to go to Computer Science SE and ask there, "How do I compute the time complexity for this algorithm". *Please note that I am not sure if such questions are welcomed there. You might be told to read about complexity analysis.* I just gave you 1st hint. You are running a computational function with the same parameters more than once, it's a no-go for any performance targeted algorithm. I am too lazy, too busy, and have too little experience/knowledge to calculate time complexity of your recurrent beast. Sorrey and good luck.

Comment: @luk32 ok,I will do as what you say :)